# string to integer in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table of users:-

```
|usersname|
|  52125  |
|  John   |
|  kathy  |
|  52451  |
```

I need to delete entries where username is made of only numbers like 52125 and 52451. i don't want to delete john and kathy. datatype of column is varchar and I'm using PostgreSQL. can someone help.

Comment: Use a regex match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regexp to find such rows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE usersname ~ '^[0-9]+$' -- user name made only of numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT username 
FROM users 
WHERE username !~* '([a-z])';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually remove the users from the table, use `delete`:

```
delete from t
    where username ~ '^[0-9]+$';
```

You can use this logic in a `select` to check the rows before deleting them.